# What service account permissions are required for firebase cloud messaging on app engine?

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-accounts

we have an app engine app that we want to use to send push notifications through fcm. We're using the firebase admin sdk (go) and authorize with a service account json. It seems like the roles required on the service account are different once the app is deployed. Using `dev_appserver.py` Firebase Admin is enough, but once deployed I can't seem to find a role other than Project Owner that would let the app post messages. Anything less and it seems like the app throws a `http error status: 403; reason: sender id does not match regisration token; code: mismatched-credential; details: The caller does not have permission`.

What roles are required for a service account to send messages to fcm on an app engine app? Project Owner works, but, would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 7):

There is no existing role that I know that allows to send push notifications through FCM, so you'll have to create a custom role yourself and give it the `cloudmessaging.messages.create` permission as described in the [Firebase IAM Permissions documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions#messaging)